# Приложение некорректно запрашивает права (permission)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Имеется приложение, которое записывает звук и сохраняет его в памяти устройства.
При первом открытии активити, приложение выдало запрос на разрешение записи аудио. Подтвердил разрешение. Далее при попытке записать звук, приложение крашится, ссылаясь на то что недостаточно прав.

Открываю заново активити, приложение спрашивает уже другое разрешение на сохранение файлов в памяти устройства. После подтверждения прав - всё работает хорошо.

вот эти права:

```
Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Можно как то сделать так, чтобы права запрашивались сразу и на запись и на сохранение? Иначе получается не очень понятно. Я должен один раз открыть активити, подтвердить права, и закрыть активити, и снова его открыть, чтоб подтвердить еще одно разрешение. Код ниже прикрепляю:

```
public class MainActivityRecord extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 0;
private static final String AUDIO_FILE_PATH =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/recorded_.wav";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)));
    }

    Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Audio recorded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Audio was not recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public void recordAudio(View v) {
    AndroidAudioRecorder.with(this)
            // Required
            .setFilePath(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.recorder_bg))
            .setRequestCode(REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO)

            // Optional
            .setSource(AudioSource.MIC)
            .setChannel(AudioChannel.STEREO)
            .setSampleRate(AudioSampleRate.HZ_48000)
            .setAutoStart(false)
            .setKeepDisplayOn(true)

            // Start recording
            .record();
}}
```

**Util.java:**

```
public class Util {

public static void requestPermission(Activity activity, String permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, 0);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Util {

public static void requestPermission(Activity activity, String[] permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permission, 0);
    }
}}
```

А запрос делаем так:

```
   Util.requestPermission(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE } );
```

Заметьте в классе `Util`  на вход теперь идет не одно разрешение, а массив разрешений.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только вместо checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) сделал checkSelfPermission(activity, Arrays.toString(permission) ,иначе красным пунктиром подчеркивал.  Благодарю!

Comment: Да, не заметил. Но и ваш вариант тоже не лучший. Дело в том, что метод ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission() Принимает на вход всего одно разрешение  и отвечает вам есть оно или нет.  Оно не работает с массивом разрешений. Если проверить наличие первого разрешения, а не проверять второе, то может быть такая ситуация, что пользователь второе разрешение отозвал и вы получите Исключение. Значит надо проверить первое permission [0] и отдельно второе permission [1] , но это усложняет алгоритм. Поэтому предлагаю вообще удалить строку условия и запрашивать разрешение даже если оно уже есть.

Comment: Получится, что если вы запросите и разрешение уже есть, то ничего не произойдет. А если его нет, то выскочит окно с запросом разрешения. Я в своих приложениях, перестал осуществлять проверку разрешения, потому что ничего страшного на мой взгляд не происходит, если запросить уже имеющееся разрешение.

Comment: что то в классе Util убрал условие, и не запрашивает повторно всё равно. Может неправильно сделал?

Comment: Вы не поняли меня. Он и не будет повторно запрашивать. В том то и дело, что проверка не нужна. Просто не пользуйтесь условием. Повторно он запросит, только в случае, если вы отзовете разрешение. А знаете как его отозвать? Заходите в настройки, в приложения, ищете свое приложение, разрешения . И увидите список разрешений. Отключите хоть одно из них. И после запуска приложения, они запросятся повторно.

Comment: Сперва попробуйте отозвать разрешение, а потом читайте дальше , если все получилось.  Есть , одно но.  Если вы запустите приложение, получите разрешение  и не выключая приложение, зайдете в настройки и отзовете разрешение , то при попытке записать получите Исключение. Потому что запрос на разрешение делается в onCreate, а этот метод запускается единожды при запуске приложения. Поэтому разрешение нужно запрашивать каждый раз, когда вы его пытаетесь использовать.